# how to return json in the following format

Tags: php, json

i was unable to return json in the following format as it required for supersized image gallery pluggin.

```
              [ {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/kazvan-1.jpg' title : 'Image Credit: Maria Kazvan', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/kazvan-1.jpg', url : 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/04/maria-kazvan/'},
                                                    {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/kazvan-2.jpg', title : 'Image Credit: Maria Kazvan', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/kazvan-2.jpg', url : 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/04/maria-kazvan/'},  
                                                    {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/kazvan-3.jpg', title : 'Image Credit: Maria Kazvan', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/kazvan-3.jpg', url : 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/04/maria-kazvan/'},
                                                    {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/wojno-1.jpg', title : 'Image Credit: Colin Wojno', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/wojno-1.jpg', url : 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/03/colin/'},
                                                    { image: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/shaden-2.jpg', title: 'Image Credit: Brooke Shaden', thumb: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/shaden-2.jpg', url: 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/06/brooke-shaden/' },  
                                                  { image: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/kazvan-2.jpg', title: 'Image Credit: Maria Kazvan', thumb: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/kazvan-2.jpg', url: 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/04/maria-kazvan/' },
                                                    { image: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/kazvan-3.jpg', title: 'Image Credit: Maria Kazvan', thumb: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/kazvan-3.jpg', url: 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/04/maria-kazvan/' },
                                                    { image: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/wojno-1.jpg', title: 'Image Credit: Colin Wojno', thumb: 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/wojno-1.jpg', url: 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/03/colin/' },                 
                                                    {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/shaden-3.jpg', title : 'Image Credit: Brooke Shaden', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/shaden-3.jpg', url : 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/06/brooke-shaden/'}
```

I am tried with following code but not succeded.

```
$sql1 = "select file,title from multi_uploads where object_id='$postid'";

                    $result=mysql_query($sql1 ,$conn);

                            if (!$result) 
                            {
                                die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
                            }



                                                       $finaloutput=array();

                            while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result))
                            {
                                                                   $output=array();

                   $image='image : \'http://xxxxxxxxx.in/sample/newedp/admin/files/'.$row[0].'\'';
                     $title='title : \''.$row[1].'\'';
                        $thumb='thumb : \'http://xxxxxxxxxxxx.in/sample/newedp/admin/files/thumbnail/'.$row[0].'\'';
                       $url='url : \'http://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.in/sample/newedp/admin/files/'.$row[0].'\'';
                       $onerow='{ '.$image.','.$title.','.$thumb.','.$url.'}';
                    array_push($finaloutput,json_encode($onerow));  

                             echo json_encode($finaloutput);
```

give me the sample code to print json in the above format.

Comment: try to prepare array properly. then use json_encode.

Comment: Have a look at some of the example [here](http://in3.php.net/json_encode) & try again.

Comment: take echo json_encode($finaloutput); outside of while loop

Answer (score 1):

```
$output = [];
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
  $array = [];
  $array["image"] = "http://panacya.in/sample/newedp/admin/files/{$row[0]}";
  $array["title"] = $row[1];
  ...
  $output[] = $array;
}
echo json_encode($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
json_encode($finaloutput,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)
```

Instead  of

```
json_encode($finaloutput);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't address the core problem of trying to build JSON from strings manually and then shoving the strings (which aren't even valid JSON) into an array which is later json_encoded.

Answer (score 0):

The core problem is that the code is *not* using [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/json_encode) correctly - `json_encode` takes a PHP *object graph* (arrays and values, as displayed by [`print_r`](http://www.php.net/print_r)) and encodes that into JSON.

Instead, the code posted tries to build JSON manually (oops!) then tries to json_encode the manually built JSON (oops!) and then tries to json_encode an array of all that junk (oops!). The end result is that, while it will be valid JSON thanks to the final json_encode, it will look *nothing* like the intended format.

Instead, the code prepare the object graph *first* and only run `json_encode` on it once at the end.

```
$items = array();

for (each row) {
  // DO NOT build the "JSON" for the item manually; it will be
  // encoded later when the object graph is traversed by json_encode.
  // (Look how much cleaner the code already looks!)
  $item = array(
      "image" => "http://panacya.in/sample/newedp/admin/files/".$row[0],
      "title" => "".$row[1]
  );

  // Add the item to the object graph, but DO NOT encode it; it will be
  // encoded later when the object graph is traversed by json_encode.
  // (If the item is encoded here then the later call to json_encode
  //  will be encoding an array of strings and not an array objects.)
  push_array($items, $item);
}

// At the end, use json_encode ONCE on the entire object graph root.
// All the reachable values (as seen with print_r) will be encoded as JSON.
$result = json_encode($items);
```